# how do I set case sensitive paths under windows 10

Tags: windows, environment-variables, development-environment, environment

is it possible to set case sensitive env on windows?

example, for a specific folder(and all of the subolders items) i want everything (paths and filenames) to be case sensitive. if so, how do I get this done ?

i need this because, somehow windows messes up everything I have synced with the production server, so I have to be really careful with what I'm pushing to the env server.

Also, right now linux/os x aren't quite an option.

Comment: You cannot set up Windows to interpret file objects in a case-sensitive way for a single folder. It's all or nothing. The solution to your issue is a different one anyway. You need to fix the configuration of the tool to sync with your server.

Comment: How can I set everything case sensitive under windows? that'd be helpful as well.

Comment: Not convinced, that this is your solution (or how much it will break), but this [Q&A](http://superuser.com/q/266110/249808) explains, how to do it.

Comment: thanks. that'd do it